# Equivalent Statement of Chain Rule

Tags: real-analysis

This is an elementary question.

The following theorem is from *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*:

**Chain Rule** Suppose that $E$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ maps $E$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$, $f$ is differentiable at $x_0 \in E$, $g$ maps an open set **containing $f(E)$** into $\mathbb{R}^k$, and $g$ is differentiable at $f(x_0)$, Then the mapping $F$ of $E$ into $\mathbb{R}^k$ defined by

$F(x) = g(f(x))$

is differentiable at $x_0$, and

$F'(x_0) = g'(f(x_0))f'(x_0)$.

My question is the bolded part in the above statement, namely, why $g$ needs to containing $f(E)$? It seems to me that it is sufficient to require that $g$ is defined on some open set, $G$, containing $f(x_0)$, because that we can choose $x$ close enough to $x_0$ such that $f(x)$ close enough to $f(x_0)$ to make $f(x)$ belongs to the domain of $g$, (because that $G$ is open and that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$), for any $x'$ in E, $f(x')$ is also in the domain of $g$, as long as $d(x', x_0) < d(x, x_0)$.

Am I right? I went through the proof, cannot see where I'm wrong. If I am right, is there any reason why Rudin choose the chosen one, seems that the chosen one is weaker that the modified version, since it requires $f(E)$ to be in the domain of $g$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simplification of the setup, for example in order to consider $g\circ f$ as a map defined on $E$ in the first place. If you only have that $g$ is defined in some open set $U$ containing $f(x_0)$ you can simply replace $E$ with it sopen subset $f^{-1}(U)$ and  $f$ with $f|_{f^{-1}(U)}$. So we see that this seemingly weaker (because it has stronger conditions)  theorem is not weaker after all.